# What is the most conventional way to change my variable value in Java?

Tags: java

In a class I have something along the lines of the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static boolean running;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setRunning(false);
        //running = false;
    }

    public static void setRunning(boolean running) {
        MyClass.running = running;
    }
}
```

I was wondering what the most conventional way of changing the value of 'running' is, seen as I have access to using the setter method that I use in other classes, as well (somewhat)direct access to changing the variable value without calling a method.

I understand that simply doing `running = false;` may be more efficient (correct me if I'm wrong) but I am unsure on what the convention is for a class to change its own local variable where others would use its setter method.

Comment: It depends.. If you want to use `setRunning` from outside, you.. must use it in order to change `running`..

Comment: `setRunning` is used outside the class, I'm talking about changing it within the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you're question is. I think you're asking how classes should alter their own variables.
If that is the case, classes should not invoke their own Getter or Setter methods for local variables, just accessing the variable directly should suffice.

Edit: this may be a stylistic thing, but I suggest using the "this" keyword in your Setter instead of "MyClass"
So instead of MyClass.runner = runner, use this.runner = runner;

Comment: That's pretty much what I was asking, I was unsure whether or not it was more conventional for a class to use its own setter rather than directly changing it.

Comment: > Edit: this may be a stylistic thing, but I suggest using the "this" keyword in your Setter instead of "MyClass" So instead of MyClass.runner = runner, use this.runner = runner;

The variable is static so it has to be accessed that way

Comment: you cannot use **this.runner** because its type Static

Answer (score 0):

If `running` is used outside of the class, then it has to be `public static boolean running;`

Inside of the class, saying `running = false` would do just fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's bad practice to set a variable like that as public, hence why getters and setters are used. However I'm getting the impression that simply `running = false` when used locally in the same class is the preferred way.

Comment: Exactly. Getters and setters are good when you want to control what happens when the value is changed